# Collapsible tree not showing subtree at second level

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a collapsible tree from some JSON data.  It renders fine and if I don't add in the `else` clause in my event handler, the showing action works all the way down the tree.  As it is, hide/show works ok at the first level of the tree, but at the second level it appears that both the `if` and the `else` sections are being executed.  Thus, the next level of children are shown, then immediately hidden.

I have a [working example here](http://codepen.io/jmargolisvt/pen/vGbEyW).  If you turn on the console, you'll see that a click registers both the 'hiding' and 'showing' debug messages.

Why is the click registering both the `if` and `else` clauses?  How can I get the correct hide/show behavior at all levels of the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the `event` from propagating further after you have handled the `click` event.

Here's the modified `addHandlers` function:

```
function addHandlers(elems) {
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            var child = e.target.children[0];
            if (child) {
                if (child.classList.value == 'hide') {
                    console.log('Showing child list!');
                    setDisplay(false, child);
                } else {
                    console.log('Hiding child list!');
                    setDisplay(true, child);
                }
            }
            event.stopPropagation(); // <--- here we call this function to stop the event from bubbling outwards
        });
    }
};
```

---

What happens is that due to [`event bubbling`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) the event travels outwards from the target element from which it was emitted. Hence it triggers all the handlers going outwards. So in your case, it actually *shows* and then *hides* the sub tree.

Calling [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) stops the event from propagating outwards.